# How to map NaN in numpy to values using dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a dictionary that maps numeric values to labels. I use it to create labels for a given numpy array. The array initially contains all NaN values and some elements get populated with non-NaN values. I want to map NaN values to a label. However, this fails:

```
import numpy as np
# make array with all NaNs
a = np.ones(5) * np.nan
# populate some of it with non-NaN values
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
l = {"1": "one", 2: "two", np.nan: "NA"}
for k in l:
  if k == np.nan:
    print l[k]
# this returns false
print (np.nan in a)
```

Is this because of the initialization of the array? Why is `np.nan` not equal to the NaN values in `a`?

I am trying to get a working version of:

```
print l[a[3]]  # should print "NA", not raise keyerror
```

Comment: I haven't mentioned this yet, but it really seems like you want to be working with numpy's masked arrays.  They help you avoid all these nan problems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One interesting thing about `NaN` is that `IEEE` specifies that `NaN` doesn't equal *anything* (including itself).  Numpy and python in general follow this rule.

```
>>> NaN = float('nan')
>>> NaN == NaN
False
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

This should explain why your `print l['k']` statement doesn't ever print and why `np.nan in a` doesn't return `True`.

One workaround might be:

```
numpy.isnan(a).any()  # Check if any element in `a` is `nan`.
```

---

If I understand your comment correctly, the problem is more appropriately demonstrated by the following snippet of code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {np.nan: 'foo'}
>>> d[np.nan]
'foo'
>>> a = np.array([np.nan])
>>> d[a[0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: nan
```

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do here due to the crazy properties of `NaN`.  `numpy` arrays are essentially C-Arrays that hold floating point numbers.  When you have a free-floating `np.nan`, it has an ID (memory address) that never changes, so python can lock it down by doing pointer comparisons.  This is why the first bit worked with the dict above.

Unfortunately, when you put a `NaN` into an array, it fills the value in the array with `NaN`.  In this case, the ID of that element is relative to the location of the first element in the array -- so python can't tell that this `NaN` is the same as the one you used to construct the array (because it isn't).  Since ID comparision now fails and equality comparison fails due to the properties of `NaN`, you're a bit out of luck.

As for your value -> label conversion, you can probably use numpy builtin functionality:

```
label_array = np.empty(a.shape, dtype='|S3')
label_array[np.isnan(a)] = 'NA'
label_array[a == 1] = 'one'
label_array[a == 2] = 'two'
```

For moderately sized arrays, this *should* be fast enough...

<sup>Note, This really only works if you've put the ones and twos in `a` directly -- Not if you've done some floating point math to compute them.  e.g. `a[n] = 5. / 2.5` as precision errors could leave you with numbers really close to `2` that don't quite equal `2`...</sup>

Comment: i am trying to associate a particular element of an array, based on its position, with a label. i want to handle the case where the key of the dictionary containing the labels is np.nan. you show how to check if np.nan is in an array or not, but doesn't solve the issue with dictionary mappings

Comment: @mvd -- Sorry, I'm not understanding what you're trying here... You can use `numpy.isnan(k)` for your test instead of `k == np.nan` if that helps...

Comment: i iterate through an array and i want to make an array of equal size that has a label for each entry. the values to labels is stored in a dictionary. that means i need to get a value from the array, which is nan, and use it as a key to the dictionary. i am not just checking for equality

Answer (score 0):

NaN fails *any* comparison check, including against itself.  i.e.

```
NaN == NaN
```

is False.

Thus, your statement

```
if k == np.nan:
```

*must* return **False** for all values of k.  Instead, try this:

```
if not k == k:
  print l[k]
```

This yields the desired "NA" output.

Note that you *cannot* spoof this with

```
if k != k:
```

as this also returns **False**.

---

Does this work for you?

```
import numpy as np
# make array with all NaNs
a = np.ones(5) * np.nan
# populate some of it with non-NaN values
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[3] = 1
l = {1: "one", 2: "two", "NaN": "NA"}
for k in l:
  if not k == k:
    print l[k]
# this returns false
print (np.nan in a)

a_label = [l[a[n]] if a[n] in l else l["NaN"] for n in range(len(a))]
print a_label
```

Output:

```
False
['one', 'two', 'NA', 'one', 'NA']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own dictionary that handles NaN they way you want it:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            if np.isnan(key):
                return 'NA'
        except TypeError:
            pass
        return super(MyDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        try:
            self.__getitem__(key)
            return True
        except KeyError:
            return False
```

Test it:

```
>>> l = MyDict({1: "one", 2: "two"})
>>> l[a[3]]
'NA'
>>> l[a[0]]
'one'
>>> np.nan in l
True
```